# working with pid for a shell project but getting set but not used

Tags: c, pid

i'm getting a "wpid variable set but not used" error. anything i should be doing different?

```
int launch_shell(char **args)
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    pid_t wpid;
    int status;

    child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid == 0) {
    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) /*if executuion fails*/ {
      perror("shell error"); /* print error, else execute */
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (child_pid < 0) { /* if no child process */
    perror("nothing forked");
  } else {
    do {
      wpid = waitpid(child_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You could do something with `wpid`. Or don't assign the function result to a variable if you don't need to use it.

Comment: something like what @Barmar? isnt that what i did with the do while loop though?

Comment: You're using `status` in the `while` condition, not `wpid`.

Comment: Something like checking to see if `waitpid()` suceeds or not before using `status`.

Comment: After the `waitpid` try `if (wpid < 0) break;` and convert to a simple `while` loop. Don't loop on the `W*`

Comment: @Shawn, any idea how i can do exactly hat you said without messing up the code?